# Average of a column where the criteria is the top x% of a different column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

For the excel dataset in the below screenshot, I am looking to find the average of the numbers in column A where the criteria is the top 30% of column B. In this example, it would be the average of A6, A8, and A10. Any help would be highly appreciated!

excel dataset

[image]

Comment: in google sheets?

Comment: top 30% means what? It seems average of max value  corresponding of column B to column A.

Comment: Top 30% of the values in column B. In this case, the top 30% of column B are the values in B6, B8, and B10 (all 40s), so the result I am looking for is the average of A6, A8, and A10 which would be 17.33 (average of 18, 12, and 22). @Harun24HR

Yes, I am looking to do this as a formula in Google sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, another way of stating this is you are looking for the average of column A where column B in the 70th percentile or higher.

`=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A10,B1:B10,">="&PERCENTILE(B1:B10,0.7))`

**References**

- [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534)
- [`PERCENTILE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094093)